# 1-D conditional slice from a 2-D probability density function in R using np package

Tags: r, probability

consider the included example in the np-package for r,
page 21 of the [Vignettes for np package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/vignettes/np.pdf). 
`npcdens` returns a conditional density object and is able to plot 2d-pdf and 2d-cdf, as shown. I wanted to know if I can somehow extract the 1-D information (pdf / cdf) from the object if I were to specify one of the two parameters, like in a vector or something ?? I am new to R and was not able to find out the format of the object. 
Thanks for the help.
-Egon.

Here is the code as requested:

```
require(np)
data("Italy")
attach(Italy)
bw <- npcdensbw(formula=gdp~ordered(year), tol=.1, ftol=.1)

fhat <- npcdens(bws=bw)
summary(fhat)

npplot(bws=bw)

npplot(bws=bw, cdf=TRUE)
detach(Italy)
```

Comment: Please provide us at least with the runnable code, so we don't have to go and copy paste it from the vignettes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method suggested by JD Long will only extract density for data points in the existing training set.  If you want the density at other points (conditioning or conditional variables) you will need to use the `predict()`
function.  The following code extracts and plots the 1-D density distribution conditioned on year ==1999, a value not contained in the original data set.

First construct a data frame with the same components as the Italy data set, with gdp regularly spaced and with "1999" an ordered factor.

```
yr1999<- rep("1999", 100)
gdpVals <-seq(1,35, length.out=100)
nD1999 <- data.frame(year = ordered(yr1999), gdp = gdpVals)
```

Next use the predict function to extract the densities.

```
gdpDens1999 <-predict(fhat,newdata = nD1999)
```

The following code plots the density.

```
plot(gdpVals, gdpDens1999, type='l', col='red', xlab='gdp', ylab = 'p(gdp|yr = 1999)')
```

Answer (score 3):

The `fhat` object contains all the needed info plus a whole lot more. To see what all is in there, do a `str( fhat )` to see the structure.

I believe the values you are interested in are `xeval`, `yeval`, and `condens` (PDF density).

There are lots of ways to get at the values but I tend to like data frames. I'd pop the three vectors in a single data frame:

```
denDf <- cbind( year=as.character( fhat$xeval[,1] ), fhat$yeval, fhat$condens )
## had to do a dance around the year variable because it's a factor
```

then I'd select the values I want with a `subset()`:

```
subset( denDf, year==1951 & gdp > 8 & gdp < 8.2)
```

since gdp is a floating point value it's very hard to select with a `==` operator.